# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, .net-assembly

Complete Error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

What dependencies do I need for `Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` ?
P.S. - I don't have Microsoft Office in my local server or rather I don't want to install it.

Other solutions provided on stackoverflow did not solve my problem

Comment: You have been using the wrong assembly tag - [tag:assembly] is used for "assembly language" - What you want is [tag:.net-assembly]. [tag:assembly] is used for assembler language.

Answer (score 0):

You need the reference:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

From what I see on [MSDN Article for Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx) you need to have installed Microsoft Office.

> To complete this walkthrough, you must have Microsoft Office Excel
>   2007 and Microsoft Office Word 2007, or later versions, installed on
>   your computer.

If this is not okay with you, you should use another approaches. Also Interop has well known memory leak problem for which you should take care manually, I don't advise you to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have already added the reference in my project and still its not working, I think an assembly ref. is missing

Comment: @SiddeshKulkarni Do you have office installed? You indicate in your question that you don't. Word Interop won't work without if

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yes I cannot install it and one of my co-workers used to work with this assembly and he did it without installing office.